# swift: save file document directory

Tags: ios, swift

I use this code to save file in document directory

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL){

        let fileName = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.lastPathComponent
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
        let fileManager = FileManager()
        let destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.appendingFormat("/\(String(describing: fileName!))"))

        do {
            try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURLForFile)
        }catch{
            print("error")
        }
```

And the file saves for this path `/Documents/filename`

But I want to save the file like this: `/Documents/Folder/filename`

How to do it?

Comment: Instead of moveItem, please try moveItemAtPath
And it should work. Please check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to [create directory](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/1415371-createdirectory) first before moving the file to that directory, something like this:

```
let fileName = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.lastPathComponent
let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
let fileManager = FileManager()
var destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.appending("/Folder")) //\(String(describing: fileName!))
do {
    try fileManager.createDirectory(at: destinationURLForFile, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    destinationURLForFile.appendPathComponent(String(describing: fileName!))
    try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURLForFile)
}catch(let error){
    print(error)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create Directory like this -

```
let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
let documentsDirectory: AnyObject = paths[0]
let dataPath = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent("MyFolder")!

do {
    try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: dataPath.absoluteString, withIntermediateDirectories: false, attributes: nil)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print(error.localizedDescription);
}
```

Comment: hi Abhishek can you guide me step by step for 1) how to create directory 2) how to save pdf file from url in newly created directory 3) how to share that pdf file from that directory 4) after sharing is done how to delete that directory. Please help me.If you want to me to ask as an question will also do it for this.Please Please Please.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    // Move '/Documents/filename.hello.swift' to  '/Documents/Folder/filename/hello.swift'

do {
  try fileManager.moveItemAtPath("hello.swift", toPath: 
 "/Documents/Folder/filename/hello.swift")
   }
 catch let error as NSError {
  print("it did not worked\(error)")
  }
```

Hope it helps